# How bit manipulation works?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

There was a question asked:

> "Presented with the integer n, find the 0-based position of the second
>   rightmost zero bit in its binary representation (it is guaranteed that
>   such a bit exists), counting from right to left.
>
> Return the value of 2position_of_the_found_bit."

I had written below solution which works fine.

```
int secondRightmostZeroBit(int n) {
  return (int)Math.pow(2,Integer.toBinaryString(n).length()-1-Integer.toBinaryString(n).lastIndexOf('0',Integer.toBinaryString(n).lastIndexOf('0')-1))  ;
}
```

But below was the best voted solution which I also liked as it has just few characters of codding and serving the  purpose, but I could not understand it. Can someone explain how bit manipulation is helping to achieve it .

```
int secondRightmostZeroBit(int n) {
  return ~(n|(n+1)) & ((n|(n+1))+1) ;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider some number having at least two 0 bits. Here is an example of such a number with the 2 rightmost 0 bits marked (x...x are bits we don't care about which can be either 0 or 1, and 1...1 are the sequences of zero or more 1 bits to the right and to the left of the rightmost 0 bit) :

```
x...x01...101...1 - that's n
```

If you add 1 to that number you get :

```
x...x01...110...0 - that's (n+1)
```

which means the right most 0 bit flipped to 1

therefore `n|(n+1)` would give you:

```
x...x01...111...1 - that's n|(n+1)
```

If you add `1` to `n|(n+1)` you get:

```
x...x100........0 - that's (n|(n+1))+1
```

which means the second right most 0 bit also flips to 1

Now, `~(n|(n+1))` is

```
y...y10.........0 - that's ~(n|(n+1))
```

where each y bit is the inverse of the corresponding x bit

therefore `~(n|(n+1)) & ((n|(n+1))+1)` gives

```
0...010.........0
```

where the only 1 bit is at the location of the second rightmost `0` bit of the input number.

Comment: I understood and find out the second set bit ..
(~(~n|~n+1) & ((~n|~n+1)+1))